# Using variables on multiple PHP pages for mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a member login page and now I am working on a restricted 'Member's Only Section'. I am fairly new to mySQL and I am also practically trying to teach myself. My question is related to authorizing someone who has just logged in, to allow them to go to that restricted section. Vice versa, if they are not logged in, they should not be able to access it or find an error. Below is the code that I have from my login page and also the code for the restricted section...

```
echo "Welcome."; //Successful 
echo "<br>";
echo "<a href='thankspage.html'> Click here </a> to continue to the Member Page."; // creates a link to go to.
$sql = " INSERT INTO Login (loginName,loginTime) 
VALUES ('$username', NOW() ) "; // creates the login time.
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die ($mysqli->error); // shoots an error if i did something wrong.
$_SESSION[‘logname’] = $userlogin;
$_SESSION[‘auth’]=”yes”;
```

Below is the code for the information section:

```
if ($_SESSION[‘auth’] != “yes”)
{
    header("Location: membership.php");
    exit();
}

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE)
or die("Failed to connect");
$sql = "SELECT firstName,lastName FROM Member 
WHERE loginName=’{$_SESSION['logname']}’ ";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);
```

My main issue is that I can access this page whether I am logged in or not... is the variable `$_SESSION['auth']` not a global variable?

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` at the beginning of both scripts?

Comment: It looks like you're using "smart quotes" in your scripts. I don't think PHP allows that, you have to use ASCII single quotes.

Comment: Yes, I do. I placed it above my variables for $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE), so I did not want to add that in my code. But it is there.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_SESSION)` show when someone goes to the second page when not logged in?

Comment: How is $username generated, may be better to prepared statements.

Comment: I'll try var_dump at the end of the second code. The $username is generated when a person places their data into the form. The first section of the code works. I am having trouble using the $_SESSION['auth'] variable.

Comment: array(0) { } is the result of var_dump($_SESSION)

Comment: I'd like to note that you should probably use [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers), as your current code allows for SQL injection. Using `mysqli_real_escape` is also a solution, but I'd recommend learning PDO instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using smart quotes, the result will be unexpected, and not 'yes' :

Following example:

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION[‘auth’]=”yes”;    
echo "var=".$_SESSION[‘auth’];
```

prints `var=â€yesâ€`

Replace the single and double smart quotes with dump quotes

```
$_SESSION['logname'] = $userlogin;
$_SESSION['auth']="yes";
```

and also when you check:

```
if ($_SESSION['auth'] != "yes")
```

Comment: So, just change $_SESSION[‘auth’]=”yes”; to $_SESSION[‘auth’]='yes';

Comment: you have to be more specific than that. add echos to see the variable values